# Probability of Something Happening At Least X Times Given Y Tries (Where Y is a Decimal and NOT an Integer)

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

If I know the probability that something will happen on any given attempt (let's say 25%), how would I calculate the probability that it would happen at least once (or 2 or 3 times) given a known number of attempts, but where that known number is a decimal.

For example, a baseball player will get a hit in 25% of his at-bats.  On average, we'd expect him to get 4.5 at-bats today.  What's the probability he will get at least 1 hit given this information?  At least 2 hits?  At least 3 hits?

Thank you so much to anyone who may be able to help!

Comment: "*given a known number of attempts*" is not the same as "*given a random number of attempts following a stated distribution.*"  The player can not bat a non-integer number of times, so $4.5$ can not be the known number of at-bats the player has.  You mean to ask about where the player has a random number of at-bats where the average number of at-bats happens to be $4.5$, but that is not enough information.

Comment: That being said... we *can* calculate the *expected number* of hits simply as $0.25 \cdot 4.5$.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, the question is ambiguous.

Consider the probability that the $250$ hitter gets at least three hits.

You are given that the expected number of at-bats is $4.5$.

Suppose that a batter has exactly $n$ at-bats $~: ~n\in \Bbb{Z^+}, n \geq 3.$

Set $p = (1/4), q = (3/4).$

Then, the chance of the (250) batter having at least 3 hits is
$P(n) = \sum_{k=3}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k q^{(n-k)}.$

This gives:
$P(3) = 0.015625$.
$P(4) = 0.05078125$.
$P(5) = 0.103515625$.
$P(6) = 0.169433593$.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:}}$
There is a $(1/4)$ chance of the batter having each of $3,4,5,$ or $6$ at-bats.

Chance of at least 3 hits is 
$(1/4) \times [P(3) + P(4) + P(5) + P(6)] = 0.084838867.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:}}$
There is a $(1/2)$ chance of the batter having each of $4,$ or $5$ at-bats.

Chance of at least 3 hits is 
$(1/2) \times [P(4) + P(5)] = 0.077148437.$

---

The Case 1 and Case 2 computations do not match.

However, the constraint that the batter will expect to have $4.5$ at-bats can be intepreted as fitting either Case 1, or Case 2, among other possibilities.

Therefore, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: It might be appropriate to model the number of at-bats the player has as poisson, in which case we would have enough information to continue.  That said, in reality, poisson isn't going to be perfect since in a real baseball game, every player in the starting lineup for the away team who isn't changed out is guaranteed to get to bat at least three times (*as there are nine innings with at least 3 at-bats per, compared to the 9 player lineup*)

Comment: @JMoravitz "It might be appropriate to model the number of at-bats the player has as poisson, in which case we would have enough information to continue." Agreed.  The ambiguity arose because, for $n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}}$ you could not assign a specific probability $~f(n),~$that there would be exactly $n$ at-bats.  Any unambiguous delineation of $f(n)$ must remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

This is a binomial question. Let $X$ count the number of successful events, each with probability $p$. In $n$ tries, the probability of observing $x$ successful events is
\begin{equation}
P(X=x) = (nCx) \times p^x \times (1-p)^{n-x}.
\end{equation}
So for your batsman example, the probability of exactly one hit out of, say, $25$ is
\begin{equation}
P(X=1) = (25 C 1) \times (0.25)^1 \times (0.75)^{24} = 0.006271...
\end{equation}
where $nCx$ denotes the [choice function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Then, to get the probability $P(X \ge x)$ (the probability of 'at least...') you simply add these individual probabilities. For example,
\begin{equation}
P(23 \le X \le 25) = P(X=23) + P(X=24) + P(X=25).
\end{equation}

*I think to sort out your confusion*, forget 'decimal expected number' and just convert this into a probability. E.g. simply think of 'expect $25\%$ hit' as 'the probability of a hit on one attempt is $25 \% = 0.25$ and work from there.